# SplitPanel collapsing and expanding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik, rad-controls

I have a RadSplitContainer with 2 panels.
On the middle i have the bar with 2 arrows that lets me collpasing the right or left panel. 
There is an event that let me know when this is happening :

```
private void splitterName_PanelCollapsing(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadSplitContainer.PanelCollapsingEventArgs e)
```

My question: Is there any event or technique that let me know when a panel is expanding like the one for collapsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SplitterMoved/SplitterMoving event to check panel is collapsing or expanding. Preserve the x and y of splitter location when 'SplitterMoved/SplitterMoving' event occurs, and compare these X Y with previously stored X Y to see splitter is collapsing or expanding.

e.g.

```
if (splitters1.Location.X > previous.Location.X)
{
   //Do your actions
}
```